# Creating a palindrome function in r

Tags: r

Hi I have a data frame df and wish to find out are there any palindromes in one name column.
I have test data which has 12 records in it. I know 2 of the column records for name are palindromes.
The code below will return a list using lapply of true false values.

How do I return the name that is a palindrome with the true values and how would i find out which is the most frequently occuring palindrome name?

```
is_palindrome = function(x){
  charsplit = strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
  revchar = rev(charsplit)

  all(charsplit==revchar)
}

dfnamelc = tolower(as.character(df$Name))
listtest = as.list(dfnamelc)
lapply(listtest,is_palindrome)


example df
Linda,F,100
Mary,F,150
Patrick,M,200
Barbara,F,300
Susan,F,100
Norman,M,40
Deborah,F,500
Sandra,F,23
Conor,M,80
anna,F,40
Otto,M,30
anna,M,40
```

Answer (score 3):

It will probably be more convenient to use `sapply()` to return the results as a vector, and incorporate the results back into the data frame.

```
 df <- transform(df,
         is_pal=sapply(tolower(Name),is_palindrome))
 df$Name[df$is_pal]   ## which names are palindromes?
 paltab <- table(df$Name[df$is_pal])   ## count palindromic names
 names(paltab)[which.max(paltab)]  ## "anna"
```

I'm not sure what your third column signifies, so I'm ignoring it.

Comment: if the answer solved your problem you are welcome to click the check-mark next to it to accept it ...